# How to edit the environment variable $LD_LIBRARY_PATH?

Tags: environment-variables

I want to add the Intel MKL library path to the environment variable

$LD_LIBRARY_PATH. I added the following script in the ~/.bashrc file:

```
MKL=/home/nby/install_software/intel/composerxe/mkl # this is the path where the MKL installed
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$MKL/lib/intel64:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
```

Then I checked whether the mkl path has been successfully added. In the terminal, I tried like this,

```
source ~/.bashrc
echo $LD_LIBRARY_PATH
```

I found the mkl path is **NOT** shown. I don't know why? Could anyone help me? THX!

Answer (score 2):

How about trying this:

```
export MKL=/home/nby/install_software/intel/composerxe/mkl 
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$MKL/lib/intel64:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
```

The first export ensures that the MKL variable is defined for all child bash processes.